# I'm trying to set-up Wagtail on Cloud Run

Tags: python, django, wagtail, google-cloud-run

I'm trying to set-up wagtail and using the Wagtail on Cloud Run guide on https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-run-wagtail#5.

I'm on step 6 and here's the errors I'm facing after executing the `migrate.yaml` command

```
tep #1 - "migrate": Traceback (most recent call last):
Step #1 - "migrate":   File "/workspace/manage.py", line 10, in <module>
Step #1 - "migrate":     execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
Step #1 - "migrate":   File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
Step #1 - "migrate":     utility.execute()
Step #1 - "migrate":   File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 413, in execute
Step #1 - "migrate":     self.fetch_co
```

Comment: The error message you've given is incomplete, and the page you've linked to has no mention of a "migrate.yaml command".

Comment: The Cloud Build migrate.yaml command is here: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-run-wagtail#6, edit your question to correct the link. You have made a mistake someplace. My guess is an issue with the Cloud SQL Proxy executable (wrong platform, missing, etc.) Start over and try again. If you have a problem, post the command and the complete error message.